# copy a php file to every directory

Tags: php

I've a simple problem of copying a a php folder to some directories, bu the problem is I can't the solution for that, the idea is that I've an Online Manga Viewer script, and what I want to do is I want to add comments page to every chapter, the I dea that I came with, is, I create a separate comments page file and once a new chapter added the the comments file will be copied to the folder of the chapter :

Description Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYE0.png

What I to know is how can I do it knowing that I will use Disqus commenting System.

**Functions used in the script**:

```
function omv_get_mangas() {
    $mangas = array();

    $dirname = "mangas/";
    $dir = @opendir($dirname);
    if ($dir) {
        while (($file = @readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (is_dir($dirname . $file . '/') && ($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) {
                $mangas[] = $file;
            }
        }
        @closedir($dir);
    }

    sort($mangas);

    return $mangas;
}

function omv_get_chapters($manga) {
    global $omv_chapters_sorting;
    $chapters = array();
    $chapters_id = array();

    $dirname = "mangas/$manga/";
    $dir = @opendir($dirname);
    if ($dir) {

        while (($file = @readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (is_dir($dirname . $file . '/') && ($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) {
                $chapter = array();
                $chapter["folder"] = $file;
                $pos = strpos($file, '-');
                if ($pos === false) {
                    $chapter["number"] = $file;
                } else {
                    $chapter["number"] = trim(substr($file, 0, $pos - 1));
                    $chapter["title"] = trim(substr($file, $pos + 1));
                }

                $chapters_id[] = $chapter["number"];

                $chapters[] = $chapter;
            }
        }
        @closedir($dir);
    }

    array_multisort($chapters_id, $omv_chapters_sorting, $chapters);

    return $chapters;
}

function omv_get_chapter_index($chapters, $chapter_number) {
    $i = 0;
    while (($i < count($chapters)) && ($chapters[$i]["number"] != $chapter_number)) $i++;

    return ($i < count($chapters)) ? $i : -1;
}

function omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter) {
    global $omv_img_types;
    $pages = array();

    $dirname = "mangas/$manga/$chapter/";
    $dir = @opendir($dirname);
    if ($dir) {
        while (($file = @readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($dirname . $file . '/')) {
                $file_extension = strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, ".") + 1));
                if (in_array($file_extension, $omv_img_types)) {
                    $pages[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        @closedir($dir);
    }

    sort($pages);

    return $pages;
}

/*function add_chapter_comment($dirname){
    $filename = $dirname.'comments.php';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {

    } else {
        copy('comments.php', .$dirname.'comments.php');
    }
}*/

function omv_get_previous_page($manga_e, $chapter_number_e, $current_page, $previous_chapter) {
    if ($current_page > 1) {
        return $manga_e . '/' . $chapter_number_e . '/' . ($current_page - 1);
    } else if ($previous_chapter) {
        $pages = omv_get_pages(omv_decode($manga_e), $previous_chapter["folder"]);
        return $manga_e . '/' . omv_encode($previous_chapter["number"]) . '/' . count($pages);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function omv_get_next_page($manga_e, $chapter_number_e, $current_page, $nb_pages, $next_chapter) {
    if ($current_page < $nb_pages) {
        return $manga_e . '/' . $chapter_number_e . '/' . ($current_page + 1);
    } else if ($next_chapter) {
        return $manga_e . '/' . omv_encode($next_chapter["number"]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function omv_get_image_size($img) {
    global $omv_img_resize, $omv_preferred_width;
    $size = array();

    $imginfo = getimagesize($img);
    $size["width"] = intval($imginfo[0]);
    $size["height"] = intval($imginfo[1]);

    if ($omv_img_resize) {
        if ($size["width"] > $omv_preferred_width) {
            $size["height"] = intval($size["height"] * ($omv_preferred_width / $size["width"]));
            $size["width"] = $omv_preferred_width;
        }
    }

    return $size;
}
```

And thanks for all of you!

Comment: If you're wanting to use Disqus, you may want to [look here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/topics/215154/articles)

Comment: The problem is in the copying of the file, how can copy the file to every new chapter

Answer (score -1):

Include the following line in all of your pages in a small php statement, if it covers two folder paths, use this. Which I think in your case it does.

```
<?php
include('../../header.php');
?>
```

And then save this in the main root directory. Which in your diagram is called "Main Folder"

Comment: but, this is for what?

Comment: The name of the file I use here is just a placeholder, but this file will contain what needs to to be carried over to all directories. So, the "header.php" will contain all of the php you need to be carried over.

Comment: http://mangastream.com/read/naruto/669/end if you visit that link this is the last page of the chapter on naruto number 669, if you click next you'll be redirected to the comments page, that's what I want to do